# More link always open the first one

Tags: php, html, template-lite

I retrieve all comments from my db.

If comment is longer than 95 , template_lite function truncate it.

```
   <form action="#" method="post" />
    {foreach value=users from=$comment2}
    <tr>   
        <td>{$users.ADD_DATE}</td>
        <td>{$users.USERNAME}</td>
        {if $users.COMMENT|count_characters > 95}
         <td width="340px"><span id=comment12kisa_{$users.ID}>{$users.COMMENT|truncate:95:"..."}
            </span><a href="" onclick="$('#comment12kisa_{$users.ID}').html($('#comment12kisaa_{$users.ID}').html()); $(this).remove(); return false;">devamı</a></td>
        <td><center><input type="checkbox" name="checkComment[]" value={$users.Movie_Comment_ID}-{$users.MOVIE_ID} ></center></td>

            {else}
            <td width="180px">{$users.COMMENT}</td>
            <td><center><input type="checkbox" name="checkComment[]" value={$users.Movie_Comment_ID}-{$users.MOVIE_ID}></center></td>
            {/if}

            <span id="comment12kisaa_{$users.ID}" style="display:none">{$users.COMMENT}</span>

</tr>
        {/foreach}
</table>

    <p align="right"><input type="submit" name="deleteCommentonMovie" value="Seçilen Yorumları Sil"/></p>

     </form>
```

When user click "devam" link, it must open the full of comment. However , when i click it, it only opens the first one.I click the fourth one, but it opens the first one .Why ? What might be the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not using the right jQuery method (twice). Your CMS appears to be loading the content into a span that's hidden by default. Your selector appears correct, but rather than using .html() try something like slideDown() or show().

```
$('#comment12kisa_{$users.ID}').slideDown();
```

If you're testing this locally, your user id might be the same for each comment, in which case you'll have multiple of the same ID across the comment thread. Try setting "12" in your ID to be a different integer for each comment. More specifically, above your foreach, initiate a variable and set it equal to zero, then increment that value at the bottom (but inside of) the loop.